# R- iGraph Error: weight vector too short, Invalid value when applying community detection alogrithm

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I'm using igraph in R. I want use community detection algorithm with weights on the edges. However, I keep getting an error saying the weight vector too short.

### Here's my code.

```
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda"),
                     age=c(48,33,45,34,21),
                     gender=c("F","M","F","M","F"))

relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                        same.dept=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
                        weight=c(4,5,5,2,1,1))

g <- graph.data.frame(relations, directed=FALSE, vertices=actors)

print(g, e=TRUE, v=TRUE)

community <- multilevel.community(g, weights = TRUE)
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
    Error in multilevel.community(g, weights = TRUE) : 
      At community.c:2424 : multi-level community detection:
      weight vector too short, Invalid value
```

Can anyone help me intepret this error, and see what's wrong with it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the helpfile `?multilevel.community`

```
weights:    
Optional positive weight vector. If the graph has a weight edge attribute,
then this is used by default.Supply NA here if the graph has a weight edge attribute
but you want to ignore it.
```

I'm guessing from that you want:

```
community <- multilevel.community(g)
```

not `weights=TRUE` which would be taken as a single length vector - hence the warning -- probably???

Comment: Exactly. As the docs say, you don't need to say anything to include the weights. Your graph has a `weight` edge attribute, so just say `community <- multilevel.community(g)`.